# Wp-admin menu text appears in wrong rows

Tags: wordpress

[image]

My WordPress admin panel sometimes appears normal. However when I select certain menu items, some items will appear over others, leaving some rows blank. Each time I do hover or select a menu item, whether it glitches or not, is random. It doesn't always glitch the same way each time. I've disabled all plugins and updated to the latest version of WordPress.

My custom CSS is:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.col-lg-8 {
    width: 80%;
}

.col-lg-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#menu-item-112 > a {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul#menu-footer-menu {
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#nav_menu-2.widget-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im taking a wild guess and saying you're using Chrome.

In the latest couple of versions, there seems to be a problem which is causing this issue and it has been reported to both Chrome and WordPress.

There are two quick fixes in the mean time till someone fixes the issue.

### Option 1 - Fix in Chrome

- Go to chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint
- Enable the "Disable slimming paint" option.
- Ensure that the "Enable slimming paint" option below it is not turned on.
- Relaunch Chrome.

### Option 2 - Fix in WordPress

Add this to your functions folder.

```
function chromefix_inline_css()
{ 
  wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0); }' );
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chromefix_inline_css');
```

Or you can download this plugin to fix the issue for you

- [Chrome Admin Menu Fix - Raffjones](https://github.com/raffjones/chrome-admin-menu-fix)

Comment: Yup, I'm using Chrome. Thank-you